# How to force eclipse to create files with 755 permissions?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, chmod

I very often write some bash or python scripts. 
I would like to force eclipse creating new files with permisions 755.

I know I can do it by External Tools like this:

> Location: /bin/bash
>
> Arguments:
>
> chmod 755 script_name.py && python script_name.py

I just don't want to chmod or create External Tool every time. 
Is there any eclipse config?
Maybe there is a way to set some chmod in Ubuntu to force creating files with 755 permissions by <strike>my user</strike> eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `umask 022` (you might consider adding it to `$HOME/.bashrc`).

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/umask.1posix.html

Comment: It appears that the question has been edited afterwards to say that it should apply to files created by Eclipse.

Comment: Yes it's because, when I tought some more about it I realized I don't want to create all files in chmod 755. I would like to create files with chmod 664 using vim, touch, gedit.. etc. When I use eclipse I would like to create files in chmod 755.

Comment: Anyway is it possible to use umask 022 to it?

Comment: Maybe try something like: `(umask 022; /path/to/eclipse)`